# Transfer perframe metadata from webrtc client to browser

Tags: webrtc

I know this question was already asked number of times a long time ago,but always remained unanswered.
I have webrtc client which transmits stream trough server(flashphoner) to browser. I need the way to mark specific frames by 4byte label on client side and parse this label in browser using js code.
Other theoretical ability is to add textual/qrcode watermarks and parse it on browser side using some ocr or qrparser library. The problem that i dont know how it possible to access decoded frame data on browser side. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While something like this hasn't been possible in the past, the WebRTC Insertable Streams / Encoded Transform ([specification](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-encoded-transform/)) API allows this but browser support varies.

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/insertable-streams/endtoend-encryption/ shows a sample that a trivial XOR encryption and, more important for your use-case, adds a four-byte checksum.